# Check if String doesn't have any letters but only numbers

Tags: java, string, char, int

How can I check if a String in java has no letters, only numbers? Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use regex: `yourString.matches("\\d+")`

`\\d` means one digit 0-9, `+` means one or more, combined `\\d+` is equal to one or more digit :)

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expression:

```
string.matches("\\d*");
```

`"\d*"` means "A digit (0-9) zero or more times." Alternatively, you can replace "*" with "+" to mean "one or more times".

Answer (score 3):

org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isNumeric(String) verifies that all characters in the input string are digits.

It's implemented as (if you don't want the 3rd-party dependency):

```
    int sz = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)) == false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over the string and check each character (possibly more efficient than doing it with a regex, if performance is a consideration).

```
boolean isAllDigit(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      if (s.charAt(i) < '0' || s.charAt(i) > '9') {
        return false;
      }
    }

   return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I seem annoying, but how is regex slower then iterating through all of it? I'm a beginner, just asking the theory behind it

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how the regular expressions are implemented in Java, but the usual way to do it is to compile the regular expression to a finite automaton, and then run the automaton on the string to see if it matches. In this case, the automaton is fairly simple. However, in either case, you will be iterating over the whole string. So, the cost of using the regex is apprioximately:  'build automata' + 'iterate'. The cost of the code above is just 'iterate'.  So, if you have twenty billion strings, the above code will be faster.

Comment: If you have just one very long string, I don't think it will be a difference, since you build the automaton only once regardless of the string length, and its size is determined by the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just put it in a try/catch?

```
    String number="a123.2";
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(number);
        System.out.println("It's a number");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("This is not a number!");
    }
```